# "Limit allowed HTML tags" filter is deleting Ckeditor table styles

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, input-formats

I'm using the "Limit allowed HTML tags" filter in my text format and put this to the allowed tags: `<th style>`

Anyway my table styling `<th style="width: 60%;">` added in Ckeditor is filtered out. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Limit allowed HTML tags" filter triggers Drupal's XSS filter, which strips all style attributes.  So you cannot use `style` attributes and "Limit allowed HTML tags" at the same time.

[There are stalled efforts to eventually address this by modifying how Drupal performs XSS filtering.](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3109650)

Answer (score 1):

`style="width: 60%;"` is an [html attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp), not a tag.

> I put this to the allowed tags: `<th style>`

Therefore, you need to remove the `style` part and just put [table header tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_th.asp) `<th>` in the allowed tags.

Comment: It's possible to allow attributes for a tag. But not `style`, which is always removed by the "Limit allowed html tags" filter, because you can use it for XSS attacks.

Comment: ok, there is really nothing which doesn't exist... so, then I have no choice than adding classes and style it in the css file.